# Cross-validating a survival model with right censoring?

Tags: cross-validation, survival

Is it sensible and possible to cross-validate a survival model? Does it depend on whether there is censoring? If not, why? If the answer depends on the model, then answer for common survival models like a weibull or log-logistic model.

Comment: I've asked a similar question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168809/error-metric-for-cross-validation-on-interval-censored-data - my current approach is a zero-one loss on each observation. You could do the same thing on your survival model: take the censoring or death time for each subject and ask your survival model to predict whether the subject is alive or dead at that point, and score it zero-one.