# Error metric for cross-validation on interval-censored data?

Tags: cross-validation, jags, interval-censoring

I want to compare crossvalidated model fit (of two Bayesian models, one using a normal distribution and the other a *t*-distribution) on interval-censored data - data where the exact point is not known, just a wide interval it must fall into. In this case, it's temporal data, so the intervals are 'before' or 'after' a check-time.
Since I don't know the exact datapoint, I can't compute the usual mean-squared error, and it's not too obvious to me what kind of error I *can* compute.
Thinking about it, I think one can define a zero-one loss based on whether the model's estimate of before/after matches the heldout datapoint's before/after intervals.
This seems to make sense but I'm not sure it's right or that I coded up an implementation correctly. Thoughts?

---

In this case, the interval-censored data is collected as a specific check-time and then a boolean. The data is whether the mail was delivered when I checked each morning over the past two months, and so we're modeling my local postal service. The raw data looks like this:

```
                  Date Delivered Time
1  2015-06-20 11:00:00     FALSE  660
2  2015-06-21 11:06:00     FALSE  666
3  2015-06-23 11:03:00      TRUE  663
4  2015-06-24 11:05:00      TRUE  665
...
```

Most survival libraries or other statistical libraries require interval-censored to be in interval format. In this case, we define the low/high endpoints as 0 or 1440 (since the day begins/ends at midnight) and work in minutes-since-midnight, yielding data that looks like this:

```
   Time1 Time2
1    660  1440
2    666  1440
3      0   663
4      0   665
...
```

(If the mail was not delivered at 11AM/660-minutes-since-midnight, then it must have been delivered sometime in the 660-1440 interval; while if it *was* delivered at 11:03AM/663, then it must have been delivered sometime in the 0-663 interval.)

Full data & formatting code:

```
set.seed(2015-06-24)
library(lubridate)
fromClock <- function(ts){ (hour(ts)*60) + minute(ts) + (second(ts)/60)}
toClock <- function(t) {
   h <- floor(t/60)
   m <- floor(t - h*60)
   sprintf("%0.2d:%0.2d", h, m)
}

mailInterval <- data.frame(Date=as.POSIXct(c("2015-06-20 11:00AM", "2015-06-21 11:06AM", "2015-06-23 11:03AM",
                                 "2015-06-24 11:05AM", "2015-06-25 11:00AM", "2015-06-26 10:56AM",
                                 "2015-06-27 10:45AM", "2015-06-29 10:31AM", "2015-06-30 10:39AM", "2015-07-01 10:27AM",
                                 "2015-07-02 10:47AM", "2015-07-03 10:27AM", "2015-07-04 10:54AM", "2015-07-05 10:55AM",
                                 "2015-07-06 11:21AM", "2015-07-07 10:01AM", "2015-07-08 10:20AM", "2015-07-09 10:50AM",
                                 "2015-07-10 11:10AM", "2015-07-11 11:12AM", "2015-07-13 11:05AM", "2015-07-14 11:14AM",
                                 "2015-07-15 11:40AM", "2015-07-16 11:24AM", "2015-07-17 11:03AM", "2015-07-18 10:46AM",
                                 "2015-07-20 11:05AM", "2015-07-21 10:56AM", "2015-07-22 11:00AM", "2015-07-23 11:17AM",
                                 "2015-07-24 11:15AM", "2015-07-27 11:11AM", "2015-07-28 10:44AM", "2015-07-29 11:18AM",
                                 "2015-07-30 11:08AM", "2015-07-31 10:44AM", "2015-08-01 11:25AM", "2015-08-03 10:45AM",
                                 "2015-08-04 10:45AM", "2015-08-05 10:44AM", "2015-08-06 10:33AM", "2015-08-07 10:55AM",
                                 "2015-08-10 11:09AM", "2015-08-11 11:16AM", "2015-08-12 11:14AM", "2015-08-13 11:10AM",
                                 "2015-08-14 11:02AM", "2015-08-15 11:04AM", "2015-08-18 11:15AM", "2015-08-20 11:20AM",
                                 "2015-08-22 11:46AM", "2015-08-23 11:04AM", "2015-08-24 10:56AM", "2015-08-25 10:26AM"),
                                "EDT"),
                   Delivered=c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
                               FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,
                               FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,
                               FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,
                               FALSE, FALSE))
mailInterval$Time <- fromClock(mailInterval$Date)
mail <- with(mailInterval, data.frame(Time1 = ifelse(Delivered, 0, Time),
                           Time2 = ifelse(Delivered,  Time, 1440)))
```

To model the distribution of delivery times, I can fit two models like the following in BUGS/JAGS, to the normal and *t*-distributions (with informative priors, where they come from is not relevant):

```
library(R2jags)
modelN <- "model { for (i in 1:n){
            y[i] ~ dinterval(t[i], dt[i,])
            t[i] ~ dnorm(mu,tau)
           }
           mu ~ dnorm(650, pow(30, -2))
           sd ~ dunif(10, 60)
           tau <- pow(1/sd, 2)

           y.new ~ dnorm(mu, tau)
           }"   
modelT <- "model { for (i in 1:n){
            y[i] ~ dinterval(t[i], dt[i,])
            t[i] ~ dt(mu,tau,nu)
           }

           nu ~ dexp(1/30)

           mu ~ dnorm(650, pow(30, -2))
           sd ~ dunif(10, 60)
           tau <- pow(1/sd, 2)

           y.new ~ dnorm(mu, tau)
           }"
```

I want to compare them. (You might say use DIC, but R2jags doesn't provide that for interval-censored data). Since this is small data, leave-one-out crossvalidation seems like a good idea. But what is the rror?

Mean-squared-error is out due to the intervaling, as are variants like absolute error. Thinking about it some, it seems to me that each datapoint is really made of two things: the check-time, and delivery status. The check-time has nothing to do with the model quality and the model isn't trying to predict it; what I want the model to predict is whether the mail is delivered or not if I were to check at particular times. The check-time is the predictor variable and the delivery-status is the response variable.

So I could ask the model's posterior predictive distribution of delivery-times (`y.new`) whether or not the mail would or would not be delivered at a particular time, and compare it against the held-out datapoint's actual delivery status, 1 if the model correctly predicts delivered/not-delivered and 0 if it predicts the opposite of what the data said. (So a zero-one loss.)

Here's a try at implementing leave-one-out crossvalidation for those two JAGS models on the interval-censored mail data with a zero-one loss defined that way based on delivery status:

```
loocvs <- function(dt, model) {
    results <- NULL

    for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
     # set up relevant data for this particular fold in the crossvalidation
     ith       <- dt[i,]
     newData   <- dt[-i,] # drop the _i_th datapoint
     checkTime <- if (ith$Time1==0) { ith$Time2 } else { ith$Time1 }
         there     <- if (ith$Time1==0) { TRUE } else { FALSE }

     # set up and run the model and extract predicted delivery times
     data   <- list("dt"=newData, "n"=nrow(newData), "y"=rep(1, nrow(newData)))
     inits  <- function() { list(mu=rnorm(1),sd=30,t=as.vector(apply(newData,1,mean))) }
     params <- c("y.new")
     cv1 <- jags(data, inits, params, textConnection(model), n.iter=10000, progress.bar="none")
     posteriorTimes <- cv1$BUGSoutput$sims.list[["y.new"]]

     # score predictions against heldout data point
     results[i] <- mean(sapply(posteriorTimes, function(t) { if (t<checkTime && there) { 1 } else { if (t>checkTime && !there) { 1 } else { 0 } }}))
    }
   return(results)
}

loocvsN <- loocvs(mail, modelN)
loocvsT <- loocvs(mail, modelT)

mean(loocvsN)
# 0.5838765432
mean(loocvsT)
# 0.5837777778
```

As expected they both seem to fit the data adequately and there is no particular reason to not use the simpler normal distribution here.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when we think of cross validation, we think of computing the error term of left out data. This is a problem for interval censored data, because we can't compute the error of censored data.

However, another way to view it is to compute the *likelihood* of the left out data. This can be computed for interval censored data. The paper that I learned this from can be found in this paper on an algorithm for [the lasso for right censored data](http://www.web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/v39i05.pdf) (see section 3.2), although I'm sure there's sources that discuss this in more detail.

While this is a form of cross validation, you have to be warned that it strays a bit from the original goal of cross validation: that is, it is *very* dependent on your assumed distribution. In fact, in the case of the semi-parametric model, which makes *no* assumptions about the baseline survival function, this will likely fail; if one of your left out observation intervals falls outside the range of the intervals used for training, your cross validation error will necessarily be $\infty$.

But it may still be better than nothing!

Comment: Huh, I'd never heard of cross-validating *likelihood* before. So the ref in 3.2 is:van Houwelingen HC, Bruinsma T, Hart AAM, van’t Veer LJ, Wessels LFA (2006). ["Cross-Validated Cox Regression on Microarray Gene Expression Data"](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbaajrercvffezw/2006-vanhouwelingen.pdf). _Statistics in Medicine_, 25, 3201–3216? I'll take a look at that; the distribution assumption may not be an issue since the point is to compare how the parametric distributions perform.

Comment: @gwern yes, my guess is that it would still work very well for checking against over fitting in a parametric model, even if it's a move away from traditional cross validation's assumption free goals.

Comment: Well, overfitting isn't the issue here (I don't have near enough data to overfit even a normal distribution) but model uncertainty & misspecification - I don't have much good reason to believe the underlying data is normally distributed. If I use LOOCV then hopefully the undefinedness won't be an issue since all the n-1 data will be available each time. Would you have happened to have seen any R or JAGS implementations around?

Comment: @gwern I'm not aware of any LOOCV code for R or JAGS. This is motivation to build this into my `icenReg` package, but that might take a bit.